# What is this dirt on the top of my high ceiling wall, how do we remove?

Tags: ceiling, attic, mold, dust

We just noticed there is some dirt on the wall by my foyer close to the ceiling. On the other side of this wall is a small attic space.

The wall to the right, where the bar is, has a bedroom on the other side. That wall appears to be clean. It is odd because it seems to have an irregular pattern to it.

What would cause this? What is the best way to remove it?

[image: wall dirt]

Comment: Are these new since the Summer? Do you have AC running, and is it possible you have condensation on the attic side, due to failing vapour barrier? Can you enter the attic and check? If not condensation/mold, then see my dust answer. One way to distinguish from mold: black dust would be everywhere on the wall just more where darker, but mold would be only in patches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ceiling joist shadows or ghost stripes.  Usually found on ceilings and caused by slight moisture collecting extra dirt/dust under colder joists in attics.  Cleaning done by regular washing of painted wall and could try adding more insulation to that attic wall.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. A friend who does this stuff confirmed the collection of dust particles at areas of differing temperatures. 

Wiping with warm water and little soap took it right off! Not a fan of the height though!

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say, but possibly dust spun off by the ceiling fan. Or stirred around in the room and then spun to the wall.

It's the same effect as mud spinning off a bike or car wheel, called the "centripetal force".

Looks like the horizontal stripe is at the same height as the fan's blade peeking through in the picture.

But it could also be the drywall seem at 4ft. You can also see the vertical stud pattern, which suggests it's caused by horizontal air movement due to the fan.

Can you confirm this?

Wipe the walls with a dry cloth or a vacuum with brush. Be careful not to scratch the wall. Don't use water too early, as it could cause staining. Then, after the loose dust is removed, wash with a bit of light soapie water. Most paints can take short exposure to water: just enough to make dirt stick.

If you operate the fans seasonally, wipe the blades before operating them.

Make sure your furnace filter is present and clean.

Keep windows closed on dusty days. This could be outside / street pollution. For fresh air intake on "stuffy" days, use a window intake fan with filter instead of leaving a window open.

Comment: nice catch with the blurry fan blade, Holmes.